# Same actress, different characters in The Expanse 1.3 and 1.9?

Tags: character-identification, the-expanse-2015

I wondered if two non-speaking extras are played by the same actress, and if so if they are supposed to be the same character in-universe. Unfortunately they are not listed in the IMDB cast of characters.

- Season 1, Episode 3 *Remember the Cant*
  The MCRN spacer who fetches Holden from the brig.
- Season 1, Episode 9 *Critical Mass*
  Dresden's henchwoman.

The second appearance is brief and in the background, so I'm not even sure if the first part of my question is true or if it is just a similar hairstyle. If not, the second part is obviously pointless. But if they are the same, that raises the question how she got off the *Donnager*.

Comment: Screenshots might be helpful.

Comment: @JackBNimble, I'm not aware of any in the public domain.

Comment: @o.m. I'm not a lawyer but I think if you take a screenshot from your copy, it should probably be fine (since you're not making money from it etc). Depending on the laws regarding streaming and such wherever you are, fetching one "somewhere on the Internet" can probably be done too

Comment: @Jenayah, making money or not doesn't matter. They might not *bother* to come after the copyright violation, but it would still be one.

Comment: The most that can possibly happen is that they ask for them to be removed. As far as I'm aware, in the entire history of SFF:SE, that's never happened

Comment: Also, 'fair use' generally exempts it from even BEING a violation if it's a tiny fraction (one frame) of an existing work and you're commenting/critiquing the work (particularly, analyzing whether a character is meant to be the same or different).

Comment: Though I suspect the answer is just "It's filmed in Toronto.  They have a smaller talent pool than Hollywood and reuse more often" (particularly in cases where it's a non-speaking, non-named role.

Comment: Well I don't see any duplicated names in the credits for each episode on IMDB (except for primary cast who are obviously playing the same character in each.)  It's possible this actress in uncredited in one or both lists, though.  I understand and respect OP's reasons for not posting screenshots, but without some kind of reference point to help further identify the actress(es) in question, I'm not sure we can properly answer this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do not appear to be the same actress.

The woman in *The Expanse* S01E03 "Remember the Cant" is [Diana Bentley](http://expanse.wikia.com/wiki/Diana_Bentley) as Sergeant Grimes.  According to [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4627683/) she also played Sgt. Grimes in S01E04 "CQB".  I believe this is the picture you're referring to:

[image: Expanse S01E03 Sgt. Grimes]

Bentley does actually have at least one line; if you listen carefully, as she's opening the door to Holden's cell she says "You."  It is easy to miss because of the noise of the door opening and the shot cutting with the door opening across her face, so you don't actually see her say it.

The woman in S01E09 "Critical Mass" is uncredited (she had no lines, and that's usually a big indicator of whether the actor is credited or not).  However, her facial structure and skin tone are different, so I don't believe that is the same actor.  Compare:

[image: Expanse S01E09 Uncredited Henchwoman]

[image: Expanse S01E09 Uncredited Henchwoman]

Both characters have dark hair pulled back in a similar manner, which may lend to some confusion.